# Centos7 unable to run @reboot command

Tags: cron, centos7, reboot

I am not able to run reboot commands on my CentOS 7 machine.
For example I've created a script: /home/usr/myscript.sh (marked executable) with:

```
echo "hello world" > example.txt
```

When Im trying to run the script from terminal everything works good.
I tried to start the script on reboot at the end of the file:
nano /etc/crontab
I added:
@reboot /home/usr/myscript.sh

and on restart, nothing happen.
I also tried to edit file:
crontab -e
its looks like a new generated file, I've typed my command, and again nothing happend.
How can I run a command on CentOS at reboot?
I tried to insert that command on my Ubuntu machine, and everything was good and worked properly.

Anyone can advise on different way (maybe 3rd party program) that will help me to manage the reboot jobs? 
Thanks for the help.
BTW, its might be duplicate, but I cant find any answer that helped me

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS/RHEL 7, the systemctl utility replaces some older power management commands used in previous versions. The table below compares the older and new equivalent systemctl commands. The old commands listed in the table still exist for compatibility reasons.

Older Command       systemctl equivalent           Description

halt                     systemctl halt              Halts the system
poweroff                    systemctl poweroff          Powers off the system
reboot                 systemctl reboot             Restarts the system
pm-suspend          systemctl suspend           Suspends the system
pm-hibernate           systemctl hibernate           Hibernates the system
pm-suspend-hybrid      systemctl hybrid-sleep         Hibernates and suspends the system

Comment: thanks but that doesnt answer my question. I figured it out by creating a crontab file for a user. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reach this out by adding a crontab file for my user.
with the following command:
crontab -u *usrname* *filename*
That allow me to run my scripts.
Thanks !